# Google Cloud Vision API - Error: Name too Long

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-vision

I am attempting to pass a `Base64` encoded image to `vision.detectText`.

```
 var image = new Buffer(mark.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '')).toString('base64');
```

OR

```
var image = mark.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
```

However, neither work and I receive this error:

```
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open 'aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQVpBQUFBRXNDQUlBQUFCaTFYS1ZBQUFBQkdkQlRVRUFBTEdQQy94aEJRQUFBQ0JqU0ZKTkFBQjZKZ0FBZ0lRQUFQb0FBQUNBNkFBQWRUQUFBT3BnQUFBNm1BQUFGM0NjdWxFOEFBQUFCbUpMUjBRQS93RC9BUCtndmFlVEFBQUFCM1JKVFVVSDRBUUhDQVV1SFhXSGFRQUFLQ2RKUkVGVWVOcnRuUWRVVk5mYTk4MU4xdnZkOTY3MWZlOTk3NzJKTmRGRUlZQ3A1aVpSTEFoVEdRYm16QXlJTGZZYUUxczB0c1NvMFZnd2xoZzFKckhFUkkySjNhakFEQjNzQld5Z1lsZnNvbEtrei9mc3M1bmhNQVBJSU9CNDgvK3R2V1lOTTRkaHp0SDlXOC96bkYwYVdBQUE0Q21oQVM0QkFBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFHRUJBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBTUlDQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlRRkFBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xBQUFnTEFBQWdMQUFBQkFXQUFCQVdBQUFBR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBZ0xBQUFBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFHRUJBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBTUlDQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlRRkFBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xBQUFnTEFBQWdMQUFBQkFXQUFCQVdBQUFBR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBZ0xBQUFBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFHRUJBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBTUlDQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlRRkFBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xBQUFnTEFBQWdMQUFBQkFXQUFCQVdBQUFBR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBZ0xBQUFBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFHRUJBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBTUlDQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlRRkFBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xQTDJVNEx3QWhBVmN1Q2VYRkpVVUY1Y1VsNVR2MUpXOS9yU2NGSDN6b3BJaWVyUjdpNzllVWdLRFFWamdxYUlTU1ZYY3lSMWZkR1ZWVlN3cGg1TjlTblVNSUt3L3I2cHVQcndWZlQxdTZlbmxFNU9uRHRrL3FzK2VvZjMyRFB2b3dKZ3BSMmV1UEx0bXo2MzlEd3F5cW5DQmE2b3F2N2pnYU9hSjlSYzJmWFg4NjVFSHh3L1kreEdkMThDOXc4Y2UvbXgrNnJkL1hBay9uMzNSZGdXZUZoY0RDT3ZQbUFEeS9rbVArMjhmbkp3eUl6QTJ0SDJFc2wyNGpCNDdSYXA5SXYycGRZeFVlMGNvMm9iTDZFbElmSyt3azkrazNUOWRXVnptSWlmRnY5WDFoemZKczcxM0QvRTFCZEJKZVVmSU8wYXFPb2tuUlk4ZDJKbks2VVZWbEg3RWdVOTNYSTNJTFhyb21pY0ZJQ3pZcXRSV3grK2xqam80bm5veVdVbG1EbEpIRy95ampmN1JCcldraWE4WTFkRjZQNU9XT3JtZldUdjkySnhMT1ZmS0JPRUNaU0NwcXJJS3NuNU1YNjJONlVLZTdXelNrSktzcCtCNFhnWkZsSTVPbjg2clY5SWc4N1VZMTQ4ZkFZVDFwN01WUFJhVkZDMVBYOTNaRkVDeEJ1KzkxTEdWVVVJVmpmZDhldEl1UWs1UHZqK3o2bTUrcHZpQlQ3SU1KQzJyNVJYbmI3K3lxMXRDMzdiaGZ1UmZMcW1xVDRvYVAzMGZrNGEwUlpIbW5meTdTQThoTE9BYXRoS2pvZnNGRDhZZG52emVMbC9xcnR4QlRqWDZGYms1aU9JWFExd1BpbVV5Y3E5WnJNTUZiRlh0T3BVWDl5TjNDdjh6RHdxeXRseitvKy91b1NRZHlnR3I0OThLdFVVbjFUMngzOW1zODNBV2hBVmNJcllpVzMyNGZ6VEZJSnJvNE1wNk5iMXVhMVZFVzVRZVVnK256NWwyZEhiU3piM1poVGwyZjY3SU9xU0FaNDVjWk00Mi91djBPZUpIbGZOZ1lVbmhzY3dUaTA0dDZ4TGZpMVRsWS9LbkxFOFZYZGwzRnFvK0tXcDBMaDBqMVVHeG9XY2VuSVd6SUN6d2hLRWVQdWJRSkdhcm1PQUt1blMwbnNjbU1uTWdaWXNVcWxBa3hkMVVZU2ZuYjlFeDNoR0tEcEdxcmdsOVo1NllGNUVSZFNIN0V2Mmh1dFB1alljM0UyN3UrZmJVOS8zMkRPTTFkVCtUdG9vRWtGZmxGRkU2T3JpelNVT2U1WEZpaGNkcm9vMmRJdjJOOFQydjVtYUl6a0lOSHNJQ1Q2TFdRNC9VeVNrVHBEaWlRdldRcE1SQ2RZQVEyNzE3WXY5dWlmMENZN3BReEVIQkN5OEpWUkZ0VWVjWDNTRW5lZEh6UG51R1RrNlpzVHg5OVk2cmtidHY3VHR4TCsxODlzVXJPUmtadWRldjVkNm9YcnRPeXJpWWZUbnR3Wm45dHcrUkIzODV0LzZyNDNNSDd4dEpFVkFIVmltWCtVVDZjL1ZVRmpSeEpiV1BVTFFYdjFWb1FwOGVTUU9DNHo4Z3lkSlhwVk9qRngxL2w2NFBuY1ZIKzhmVW5YWUJoQVVlWWFzRGR3NTNpbFE3OWs4ZWZiU0xrSk9rVnFUL2ZQaDJ5cTJIdHg4VzVlVVc1VjdOdVpaNFkrL1hKeGNGeG9aeUUxV1JUOW5NUlovbVk5THc4UkRrQlFwWUtHVGpJdERHZEFtTUNRMHNmYXlzc1hmcHlJQ1lZQXI2eUpXMlQvT09vRTlUMjI1b1ZsMVRwd05JU1JSUGZaNDhQZUpxMUxrSEY3SUtzdk9LOHpQejc2Vm1udnI5d2haS2pUdEVLSDFaZEdad2ROYjc0WDZyenE1RllnaGhnU2RUd0tMWWhNY1VkcmFpZklxRTh0TzV0WHdza3VOQWNIcThsbk45eHJHNTdTT1VYRXlQdXA4b1NNWkRsRHFPTEVaeGpiT05mb3YvUmNjUGZHUVJuZXhHU2txOWY4cnhwRGhGeFVYbWpGaksvanBHcXV6aVIvb1Q5TmY5WTR5MkFSejRMd1JoZ2ZvTHI2S3V4MUtRNHU5Z0s4cmpLS0k1Y2plRkgzejV4dlVWMjdZTW5mVlZ5TGl4WFNlT0g3dGcvdWJZcUt6YzBtcjZob3RiS01DcGpyTWVXY3V2WnF2QlgrRkZLKzl3K2F3VDh3dUtDK2hyNStROWpEMThjTXIzUzN0K1BqSDQwekg5cDAyWnQrYm40K2ZTK1VsZGYzaHo0TjZQT3pnNGkzNmtySE4rNm1JRVdSQVdxRzlHSFp4QWZWSWFYcEVPS0g2aGxweDVqQjl6TFAzTSs3MC8rQitmamszOVZjM0Uxa2dwYjZ5U3k0WU1pdHEvangvejY0V052QjVVTTVYVVF5UFJrSnFuSHAwbGlvYmRaMXl3YnMzek1sOXFkRVl2YXRSTjFNcUdDbGtySVdqUzRrV1pXUS9vTUVxQlAwZ2E1R1B5dDdzK0ZIZ0tjZDN1NU45QmtBVmhnWHJKQk1XYlhHZXp6dk9rekQ0TWlaQ1RnQ3ppM1VNNnJyaTQrTVRaczdJaGcxdnBBbHVIR0wyQ0RWNzBHR0o4S2NDL3FiL3k1NTA3K0dkT1Rwa2hCbXRHRjdTVk9scmYyYVRwa1RUZ1hzRjlTK213MHBLaTR1TE5NZEVlUnIwbm5aSFk2T3hlTlFqLzh1dXNHejNxWmlielVmTGRZN3pRNW5pSmRseU5zSWhEYmZIZkNjSUNkUXZ2WnBzdWJXc1hMcGNxaGtJSm4wai8vbnMrNGtsVFNXbE5oeVUrRVh0MlV4amlhZFJUbCthTm5PV3UxOUdMaWNsSDZJRFQ5OCt5eXJwWlYrT1VyUzZGWmFBQU1QeXFXYXFZWXZHOFBsKzZwTEZTN2lXcWlwcUhRWGc5Tk9SZk10LyswNmJ5dzJhZldPQmQvaXBKZ3pWRVdCQVdxS2NDMW96amM3MGo3THNpS1d6anBhMzBia0Z4b1RRY3UzSG5UcHNlM1NqSThwQTRpMElTRXBaMjVJaWlZbWFCS1NrelhURElJb0YyTmdWUWVQWFFPcE81MU5wRjdEdHZqWTJsWkpDQ0xOdEo4Zk9pdEhkcmZDd2RrSExudUYyUXhlTzFYcnNINXhmbncxa1FGcWlYck5CU01tVGZxRTdsN3c5U2VxaUsxcC9QdnNnUEtCWXBMR1RtT25udUhFVWZGRko1U0RvMk5lcnE1S3lvQTZ5WXRlTktwTGZyVmJLNGhlZWUvTVptcXlMeHZQSUxXQlQ1MC9adDVDYXZZS1AwcENnOWJPcXY2dkhaUkpZWEZ4ZjIyek9NQWsvYmVmRjdoUUV4SWRicFJ4QVdoQVhxVWxYMG1GZVUxejJ4UDRVZXRneE9KUVlPUFpNR0ZwWVU1QmNVcHB5eHJSakRqcC80N2FJbUtvVlgrVWlFQnlNTkZiTFpQNjJrWTA1a3BsRlBkcjF5dTRHRXRmblNkdnFHdTQrbEhFcy9ZOHNINzk1L29CejJZWE90eGk3Q29paVNZc2wzZW5TN2Z2YzJIVWJabjJQazZHY09QSEV2MVlKN2hSQVdxQWRoM1N1NEh4TGZ5OCtrdFFtTElnZ0t1Q2pzWWpyTEw1QU5IVFQ5eHgrT25FcExTa2tlSGpibnBRQi9hVElvcldRMVZzbUh6NTFEdjNVMUowTWJFOEluN3JoVUFhdERoTXAwbGVWM3l6WnZlSzFMOElZb2MvS3BVenNTRTdRamg3UENuSU9GZVhQVEJ4MU5aOWIrSnZXN2R1RXlxYkRFTkZOejRNNWhDQXZDQWs5U1dFTkZZUlVXRmZrT0h2aS92cDFhNmdLYkIvZzNVU3NydEZXWnNNSm0wMjlkY1ZsaFJhck1HVXhZdit6YThROWZuMllhRlFWUVRkVktzbkJsdG1MQ0VvSlN6ckR4cFFzaExBZ0xQT0dVc0xqU2xEQlByQ1YzblRpZWNpWEtBVWxWWHBYM2FwNFN6bHExZ3FlRXNzZEpDYzJQOGU0amFsaXlUUmRaU2hpK040bjhTMEVXcjc1VlppdWVFcmFobFBBT1N3bW5JQ1dFc01BVDE5YVFmU01yTExxbjN6OUhCOHhiOHpPWnFMWFl0NnRvdk9odVByRFh3b3J1RVRVc3Vvc3lVc1dJVDh3VnZXc1czNDJ1aWJaNDBUM3N4RUw2aGpmdTNubkg0VjVuQldHaldIVHZQbW1DQlVWM0NBczhjWGdkZmNieHNJcUdOY2grdjdDRjNqMXo1WkpYaU1GTnI2dWliMXVITlF3dkZJYzFmRkd6WVExbVFaM0Fuc2gzQ0tvNDFzcFpTVlFWSFNEZkpTZ2lCSFdpcUswYURHdElISkJkd09ZU2ZiWms4UXR5djllcUZERWIxcUNRYlltTHNXQllBNFFGbmpoODhPVEdTZ2VPRHNzcnpLTURGdisyL3A5K25hbjNlbFpTYnVjRFJ4T1NXU21uaGdOSHlVZnhRdnVsUXV1K2dtYzM0WTFoZ3U5djdKVlNaNG0ySWxXMUdTOTRkaGU4ZWdydnpSQ1VNVTQ3UzV6enJOaDVKWksrWjhidFcrMzY5S2F2WGFHekpBTkhwL0JyTmZ2RS9Fb0dqczZFclNBc1VIOFJWbnJXT2NlcE9YdzlnM1VYTnZBakp5NWVSTTVxeVNmbGtMbjRMQmJKMUp4ZjdLZm1HSnlOclRxdUZOdzBnbnVnOEtwZWNQTVh2THFMb1ZhTU5VK01FOTRhS2JSU3NIZmRCYUdsUW5qdkt6SE9NanMvTlNkeHdOMjhUUHFxUjA2bHZka3R0SkZTN2lsT3gvRVNpMW5TcVRuQ0o2TnVackpGM0pQdkh2T3JhR3BPdXdqNUgxZkNMWmlhQTJHQittVEV3WEVkSzVuOHpKZHFLQzRwWHI1MXk5dmR1elpVeUJxckZOTEp6MzVEQnBuTEpqOXZxTW5rWjFGWWIzOGl1QVVJSGlGaWdCUEM1T1c5U0ZBbkNZcElaaXZmMzRWWEJlRlZJMnNld2N4WlhoK3d0NXdOc25oWU5FVU1pMWpDZS9saWo4OG1VWnpWU0NscnFsYVdUWDdXQlU2MFRYN091OTB6YVdDRms1OTFzVjNwWFVSWUVCYW90eUNMM2R1S3ZCWnRWOGF5TGkrajFjWjBPWHdubVI5TWFkU0tiVnMrbWowemRQeW5YU2VPSDdOZy9xYVlxQWZXNVdWK3IvSHlNcFR4SlFodmpSTGN0RXhHTm1HMW0yOFZWcnpRK1ZjbUtTWXNBM3Rrd3VvaEtNTEZ4TEJteThzY241Y3Z6cFFzTEM2S1R6NDA5WWZ2ZWszK0xHVGNXSWZsWlc0TXFIeDVtYTlQTHJMZy9pQ0VCZXFORW1zeGErRGVqenRWdm9EZnFyTnJlSzI2d2dYOE1uS3VUejhXVnMwRi9DcG9KcGJjZVg4cnRGS3hqSS81U0V3TS9UYVZLNzIvTmtCb3BTNE5zaWdsYkRQQjZaVFFMdUVkdW4vVThjelV5cTRNaWN5VUVXT29aQUUvaWozcFF5NVlaeS9oUHhLRUJlbzF5TnAzKzREZGtsaU9TeVF2VDE5OTZIYnlUWEdKNUp6QzNLczVHWW5YOTFDVVFWSFlJNWRJZnZSZHZGaFdTbWUyMHJIS2VvY2Z4SnVHdHFJN1pZVWJoZGNIaW9taFhuaHJOQXV2YkJXdW1nM0w0a3NrZjViOHBYV0o1S3k4NHJ6TS9Ic24yUkxKbXgrNVJESmREWVJYRUJaNElzNWlNY0tDMUNYdjcvSjEzRExIWVJPS2Jtd1Rpb1MrMnBpUVIyNUM0Vnpna3lESXRnbys2NWlNeW13VlZlWXNaYlRRZWIzZ3UwRWM5L0FZdHJMYmhNSzdkQk9LM2owU0J4Z2Z2UW1Ga1dMSklmdEc1a3ZXM2dFUUZxalB4SkQxdS96aS9CRUh4N0hOQkN2YzVpdXFvbTIrb3ZVMTJKZTBxbUpXcktDT0Z5dFQ1a3FHbGNaYjgwUnpyVTJLdG03enBhWHpxbnFiTDc0TE5DbWJyK2FPOEFyQ0FrL1NXWGZ6TXdmdUhjNDNRSzNPNHV1MVArblBYSTJwT2VhNldDMnJXaHVwZG9yMEo1dWZ2SjhHVzBGWXdDV0tXWm41OTBZZm12RGVMdCs2VXRMVDJkVGk2alJkRW5xZnVwOE9XMEZZd0RYaUxMR1lWVkJjc1BUMDhzNG1qYXV0dVBBRVc0ZEkxZmdqWC9CUlY3QVZoQVhxMVVwOC93VkpLeTZ4N3JyT2xoZ3R2Vzk0TUlDdEVxT3J3YmdxbDI0MVdWdFo4OHY1OWRLTFk0MUpTOHExNHJMTENDQXNVSzl4Vm01UmJtaENIMS9KeWpQVmF0R2xVNWRkdE1XTHR4ZWRMRy9SUlVpK3k3WTd3eFFjQ0F2VW80bkV4OHdIRDQ2ZlRVODlmOTdXNkVkNjBYWUFMOEJUK3FPUDZ5NHpCem9ockdnMk1OMTNBeHN6NWFKdGd5RGY2ZHlFSGpwOW4wai8zYmYyMlNXRGVRWDUwbXVZUnBjeFBUM2oxaTM4TjRPd1FPM0FkNGhaSHhuWlVDSHpOQnJjOVRwcTlJUitwQmR0QjNCaDNjNjc0NXl3eEJVWGZOWUpyK3FFcWhmUGVsTE53OGhtL0xTZHgyYjhLRTFPQ0t0VGVXSHhZV3VuTDE2a3ErY20wRFZrdTNKNEJodGVVTWpHTGx4Z3NTNFZEeUFzVUF2Qyt0MXM0a3NVVUI5MkY5ZmVFNFVWWVNlc3UvbVp4dmllZm1hdFU4THF2RjRjak82U3ducFZGRmE3aGVJVVJXZUU1V1BTN0x0OTBFNVlweTVlNE1ibmw5Rkx2SXpqRmkyRXNDQXNVRXZDRWhmWTJ4d1QzVVN0WktzZVd4ZTBJbit0RGQ5bEo2enN3bXpuYWxqaVlIUy96ZUlFWnIxMW9yS3JDVXNydFA5T25JUm9jcmFHZGRST1dKUUF1b20yNGtzYjhrME1QMSs2R01LQ3NFQnRDWXQxcFBEZFNjMDBLdHRxZktLd1pNdTNickVUVmtGeFlhL2RnenFiTk9yb2Fnc3JobFdJdkhwSVZsWndNV0c1QndtZFZqdk0rM2xVazV1RFRqOG9HMzdGZlhUZzVJbFhnclRTaFF3YktXUXpWeXkzWFdjQVlZSEhndmUwK01PSFcyZzFIaEpoTlZUSzVxLzV4YTZua2JhR091eXhXcDI2KytzRHhlVVdYRkJZZWhiOVVReG92LzV5bGZtZzQ4THQvQ3JGSER6UVhMTHBHUmZXTjcrdWc3QWdMRkNid2tvNWZicVZMcWpjaGpkSzJXZEx5dVV5dkdkT1NwN1dQa0xweFBLaFpwWnR0Um5IbHVKN05kZ1Z3NnZXZmNUcVZiUVRCU3pLQjBNVCttWVg1a2lFWmMyc0pYdktjdS8vdk9NUFc2QUtJQ3p3V1BBQlZoY3lNbHAzQ1hZVGduaDA0QlZzcEk0M1pNWjAyd0cyM0dkaDJsSzc1ZDZyYnVRQ2RSSzdEZWVtY1QxaEJUT052ajNHdVh5UTc5STRlTjhJNmFKWDNFZVVSRGRVeUx4Q2pMWjlnNXFvbFZ0all4QmhRVmlnTm9WMVB6dmJ1Mi92VjRLMFhGaDhoeTdoazFIOFhkdVNmcGFLOXFlbzFvM0NYMTN5Um1Hd1pCVlRVMDJXVkxZNWkvdG8yZy9mUzRWRkYvUGx3SURkS1NrV0ZOMGhMRkE3d3JJbWhwcmhIOXUyTytZOXJYMi9QZzl5Y214U3M4M082UlRwNyt4SWQ3WTZhSCtXZjlXc2pPVnAxSG1KemNPZ2syNWp3MStrZDJ0Y3dLSkh2cFpXOVNNc0VsYmJjTm1xczJzdGttSHUvQklOL0hJYXY5bkt2eDRmaXBWKytiTEZlaHNSUUZpZ2RvS3NnZE8vYktKV1NEc2JQYVpkT0cvcmJEeWF1UEh3Wm1CTXFITlRvTVdzOEwwWkxKenhjQ1lyNUVxaXgrWTZZNk9na0VaQlhWN1NHMXNaOUc0R1BUMjIwQnNiaXkrK3FHTzdjdkVqblIzUThPWkh6dG5LdHNGOTNJMUVtOFM1aWdxTGl0UWZmZGpjUWZwWkV1a0RDQXM4TGp5ZCtXcmxjcmFmczZUKzBzeGZ0VE14MGVKd285QnhYK2pxak1haVFNYXA4SWNFNUs0WFNFbk45VVo1VCtXbnc5NVo5V25MNkNtTmprei94L0V2LzU0eS9YOFRwcjZ3ZmtLTHFjUGYxUFh4ZFRQcXlWd3RCYjFYOWFNdHNZRGx2ZGpwTWU0a2EwMU15TlhjREp2RXVZeXUzcno1WnRmUVZ0WTZJRStyaldNL3dYOHdDQXZVcXJDc2c5MGIyOTNoVXRpUGJPQUJ4VGRwM3psWHhySnQyeldtV3ZjS1BjUWNzRWxRQ0dsb3hOQjM0NmU4a0RYM1djdjhCcXpOYTFEeWRXbXpmTjJBdjVnMzc1bVU2WCtmUHVLTmQwSzFwQzJlUWo3Ni9xQk9hTjNMNlczQnJCWDNrZVVxN3RZeERTL1pqV2xReXNkOWcySHVFQmFvVlhoM09uSXFyWlV1c0N6QUNUWTBWU3Q3ZnpIWjRuQ2prTEtoQ2plbnFNNmtRbmZkbzh0VmJucDlFMTFJdjBIZXg2Yi8zYktnUWNtOEJnL0Rubmt3NTFuZXNzS2V6WnJEbXUyVm5MQy9GSkc4RmpTNE92dS92eGorMXN0NlF3dkIrSWhRSzdnbVV3aHRCYXdscDMrMFNLWTljK012L20yOXRPTE9oYlZ5K3pZTHhqUkFXS0RXYTFoWk9Ua2QrdlY5T1RDQXh3ajArRXFRdG0zdlhxVnJOa2pLV0hmek0vVnhQWnhiczhFMklHdDhWWlVzc3N6TGdvRnNzbWI4eXlYekc1Q0d1Skt5dy82U1UyVWppOUZoK1hPZklXMGxUWDIrUTNkMTA2Q1ExcFU1U3h4KzlWcGZzWFFWN2ZSS1dKMGkvZmZkUGlBVkZyODRmYWQ4MGRSYWNlZlRxdWxpN2p0K0RCRVdoQVhxeEZuOXBrNXBVcTdMNlNuSGlUMTRVSm9WY21kOWNmUXJjZmQ1bzdQYlNjaTJDeDVkS3A2bVE3WnFyak8rRXhwdzRNdC9rbmV5ck5GVDlSdHA2LzZjWnlsdHZEYm5yL28rdmswcWM1WllidSs0d3JuNWc3WWhvOTBUKytjVzVkb1ZzRzdmdS9kdXI1NHRyZU5DU25YZnA5ZTlyQ3dMS3U0UUZxaUxNdFozR3pmWUpUWDA0OHlWNWFiQ0ZZbGhSZFQxdVBZUlNtYzNvT2VEU0wwWFZ6Q0kxRk9NcmRxRWFrL08rQi9ML0FiM25WU1Z0Tkh2VW1oMmIrNS9HZnAycGpqTExqZWs0TTdOWDNoblVrMjJYT1Y3T3k5TVcxb3VIeFN2VE1TZTNjMzhWWjYyQ3FBNFpMVC90S213RllRRjZxcU1kZkRreVphNnNybTcxUDBvd3ZMLytDUHIvT2V5Q0N1N01MdHJRbCtubHg2MUpZWVRtRFZzaWFFNGlrSndNK3IzVEh1ZWJIVnZ6bk0xdGhWdkQwUm5YWi96VjU4ZUtvcmFiRFY0Wml1dDhGby82MXdjczlQNUlKMXlTdVl4cWJENHBadjQ3YUpHU3JtZDYzL1l2QWtGTEFnTDFGVkttRmRRSUI4NnBJVldZMXUyZ2RyTGdkcDl4NDlMQ3pHOHJ5NDl2Ynh0dU16cDNWS3RaYVBYaDVRVnN5Z0lhaHdVOHYybmJwUUpQazVzWlJkblVXNjRiOXEvV2hwS1I1WlJUT2V1WXdrcG0rb2M3MXd5eU84UGRveFVmWHhnYklYbHY0Nzl5OHAvdkxucGRjZlQrWElPaUxBZ0xGRHJXYUhvb3luTHZtdWtMSjhWS21YVHZsL21XTVk2bDNXQklnNUZsRTVWbzcxUjVidllyR08zQVBvVHVtWkJ3YUg5T2hYUGE1QTk1eSsxWXFzeVp5MW84TlhJMXhzR2Rta2RvdU0zS0gzV3NCQlBZYXJKN3FyZUVmTHdETE10TDdaZGs1MkpDVTNWU2xzK0tFYW02cUJSSTZRVG13Q0VCV28vSzR3L2ZGaTZRSXB0dVBiOTdHeEx1ZkVON01tTVkySGV6ZzdJc281OXB4aEh0a05vM1pmRldjMk54c1NwTDFCQTlLQ1d3aXZlc3NQK2toZjJ6TTA1ZjMyL3U2YUYxa0NKWWFlZm5aczJLQTJ2ZkV5YVhyc0g1eGZuV3lSVENQa0ZHVFRqUytraURhM0ZmSERoMnJVV3pIbUdzRUNkWm9YNUJRWEtZVU9iVTFZb3FSODNWaWwrTTBWYXlvMGdaUWVuM1Q4dE4rdHF1SytmU2R5eEprTDN5dURnZ2IzYUZTOW84Q0NzTm0zRjI3MDV6MWtXTmxneTNMMVphSWhzdmE1bXNaVzEzQzdmZW5tbk5Md3F2UWdYTHBEV3habE1wWlpuQzdvYmRDZk9ua1UrQ0dHQk9zOEs1Ni81eFc2T3pvc2F0WDdNYVB1SVRPeTNzMC9NYjFleklFdDBsaVpPNTIwSytYclpHNWJaRGZKblAvTmc3cU9IWERsUmVwLzdiTTZjdjFobU5kaXg2S1VPMjQzK0NVN1hyY3JDcTBqL2ZucytMQ2d1c0RpczBQRGxqejlJTDVlWE9LV3ArNlFKU0FZaExGREhXYUVZRHB5NWRJa2s1U1lKR2RpOFFvM0t0Ryt2WXlYclN1NVZiVXdYcHdlUlN1dFowVUxuZU9Obkc5dGVXZkEzeTB4eFVQdmphU3RiVkJVOTBxZGxoejMzM1pyVzhoaTlNcmFHdHVMQ2FoK2hsTTUydGdXa0diZHV2ZE9qVzB0ZFlObU1IREVnM1JobFJqNElZWUY2Y3RiUW1WK3hlWVhsbzRhdUU4YlpSUTI4OTY0NS8xdE5iaGRLbldVVzJzZUdCSmtDMTY1MmZ6RDNPUkpOL2h5bXJTeG56RVZIMHZIMFc3bGh6MUJVVlREN21lZ2ZtdmJlcVdnWDEwVVJWWlB0bmFXclgwMUluaUtOcld3eW1ydjZwM0xScUZqeTZ6aWdIMVpvZ0xCQXZRaEw3SWVKUjQ1SVMrODh5R3JxcjRyY3M4Y3hjQ2dzS1J5eWIyVEhTRlhOblVWZU1PdGswWHFTUzg5ZHl2VS90Ym81Ny8rUWRFcG1OY2liODB4MkdOTVE5MWRXR0NtTVdVeDhmSlliaXI5Rm9WbnhyQVlrdTZ5dzU4dy9OUHQ0bTArSDJHQ2ZHS04vamF0czRzQXJHVnViSWZoQzlpV3BnUGlUS3pkdXZOMjlxelM4S2kyM3IwTzVIY0lDOVFYdmxOMG5UU0JEZVVsdjFXdlUycEhEQ3lXRFNHMUIxc2w3YVhKemtEakVRZjhZZG1EYTZoeGpKRzBaSWdObS85WW1ZVm5qVy9QK3EzZzIweER6MSt3R2hiTWJGTXloK0lzOTBuUDJsaWdwVWh1RlpzbEwvcmxzVGV0ZU94VWRZa002eGdhcnpUcjFZOWpLTnRWNTA2VnRsdkk3UEhPdGY3NTBTVU5sV1hoRjJpSjV0ZW5SN2RydFd3aXZJQ3hRVC9EUUlQckEvaGMxYXR1OVF0dmVYeXUyYmJVTEgzaFBYbmRodzJNbGhtWGEwcEcyL0tJTjNuRk1Pc0VSbW5HYnZYOWM0eFh4NDR1SGwvd3IvWnYvZDNuQjM2NHUrTzhyQy81Mi9wdi9lMnp4UDJLK2IvckxhdmNwRzkrajBNdzMya0N5SStVOXZxcW9hY1E3ZzUrblRMZXpUK25pRm1scGJrS1FPeCtTS2dtdlp2KzBFdUVWaEFYcU44Z1MrMmZQenlhVlgzNmdOSUs0ZlAyNmZSOFduMDlPbVVITzBrUUhQNllwYk5FV3lZdk0xVDQyaERSRWorUWplaVhJRkNoRUJ1aE1XcDVGa3RUb1hlL1lFUElVVHkzVlVickgvd0prWHA5SS8rNkovZS9rMzdXclh2RVQ3elp4dk9QRitYZlA3dGR1MzBaNEJXR0JKMURKMm5QMGFJdnkwMDM0VnNiRFpzMjBsRjh5aGZmbit3VVArdTRaMmlGQzlmaHhsdFJjRkN2NVd5TW1SWlJlSHEyWGlVMGhwcDlxTVNMamRxdXRQNnFPTnNqTWdmUWs5ZjRwdTJTUWgwNnJ0bStUemh5MGhWZUxmMXVQOEFyQ0FrL0NXV0tNTU9yck1PcVpyU1U5azYxRG9GSnNjTGh0ejN2MXhlekxRbXozemlaTkxUckxVV0cyVmplZnp6ellNVklkZlQyK3d0TFY2WXNYWCtzU2JGc0ttUmY0bW1zMXNpR0RjeDQrUkhnRllZRW5saFZldkpieFZyZFE2WTB3VHpIM29SZlBYcmxpRjJmeHZuM2lYaXBGS0w2VXN0V1pzK3F1a2Eyb2VVZkllYUc5U0dJcmZrRUtpNHBDeG8xbHlhQkU0cDdpNnF3N2s1SVFYa0ZZNEluQis5NktyVnVsUTQxNDlaMzZaL0NuWS9JTEN1d0NDdDdERDkxSnBzN3Zhd3A0dXB5bGltYTJhaGN1WDN2K2Q3dll5blkxWml6LzBlNXE4RFI1Nk13WmlLMGdMT0FTY1ZiM2lST2FxSld0SFVvMmZDOTd1NWlDYjlWMytHNEtxMXZYWlc1WXU0MmlRa1dVemp0Q3NmN0N4Z3BzSlE3bTJCUWR4Vlpsa0E1UEUxY1diZE9qMnlXSEd4RUF3Z0wxWHNtU1ZtMGtpU0V2WmxGazhlT1d6UmFITmVxNHM5THVuemJFOWV3UW9kUzR2TFBJcXBURGRqWnAvcmdhWHBtdERxZW0wbG0zRW9JOHkxK0V4aW81SnVKQVdNQzFFc04xNGVIc3ZwaGtXQmFYMTBzQi90dmo0M2x4eDlGWkdiblhCKzRkM2k1Q3ppclpabGZOQk0xc1piN0FtTkQ5dHcvYTFhMXNwMy91eXBWM1AralJRcXVSWG9IV1hZSXB6UHhrL2p3THRwbUFzSUNyeFZsakZ5NTRRZTVIdlZTU0VCa280cUFXZCtpUW83TjRuSkpUbERzdGVZNXZqRVlkcTYveDlPTzZhbVpXWmZlTEN4aXcrK1BMT1Zjc2txM25wYmE2ZXZPbTc2Q0JMMnJVZG9XOFpocTFjdGlIZGl1RkFRZ0x1RVFsSytmaHc2QlJJNXVXTDJaNUJodGVFYmVLMloyU1hFR2NWY3grUEpKNjZxMEpnWHcxZDdZY2xXdUVXZ3B4UWE2QUpLUG5sN0pmZHYxQjM3T2dxTkRSVnRkdTMxWU9HK3A0MWkxMWdmVEt5WFBuRUY1QldNQkZnNndMR1JtT21aRVhkNVpCSDN2b0lLLzRsSlQvcllPcEoxOVdCYjdXVi9BUkYveFV4ZFp3RmIxYVZKVXlXbER2RnZ5MkN1K01OajdmU2I1eTYxYTdTaHgvZnVYR0RmbUhRK3hzeFhOaENyaDJKU1dpZEFWaEFaY3VaaDA4ZWRKZHI2UDR3dFBCV2ZUaTFyaFlmaVFQeXJpd0RxZWx0dElIdWdleDdVdmZtU1RJL3hEM1c0NStBdEVXRnlYYjRDdEthRHRYOEFnUlBJS01qVlR5VlgrVTI1K1pQemw5OFdLSC9uMmIrYXZzYkVVblhyWWpEbXdGWVFFWGQ5YXUzVW5OdFJvM3ZVN3FMTGJtbnhEVVRLTmF0bWtqVnhXSEM0dGN4blpPTmJJVjNEMjdDdStIQ1lvSU1kcUtxUmR0bWExUlZTS0w3em9zWXp0OXNiMFI5VUxyTHNhR1N2a3E2NGJ5NUZsK2pnbEhEci9aTmZTbEFIK3ByWGpwNm5tNTM2eFZLMkVyQ0FzOEZjNWkwY2Z2WmpPNXlkM09XV0t1Uk5ISHVHOFc1T2F4U1NvRmhZVmx3ckx1RE9ndU1GbDRmY0JpSFBsT3dUOUozSFFycWc3TVpSWlhHUlUzNldFeFhSUlQxZXVEMlZZOUZPdXhuVnlORkJ1V0NTdS9vSUFIaGl1M2IzczVNSUJpUnEveXRtb3QybXJ5MGlYY3lDaXpRMWpncVltemZvMkllRkdqZHRNSGVaWWY2K0FsWmt5QkkwZFFTc1dQRi9kbkRaVHVGTzhoYmhISW9xMXV3cnRUaE03clM1MmlpaXRkNjExWlkzbVp5M3NxVVZBbkNMS3RRdHN3Y1llZUFNRXRVT0N4bmpXWlpjSmFLYTZaUTdhNm41VTFldDdYalpSeU94Zno4eUpiVFZyOHJVV2NhSW5iZ2hBV2VNcWN0VEhLM0VLcklSazVSaUxOMk9KL3hwOTM3TENJUzBlVkU1WlVXMkswOWFvZ3ZQR2gwUFpyd1hlRG9JeGg1bUs1VzV4MWMyYVRSR0dPelNTR1psYkJNVWtsbExwUHRrMW92MFI0YXpTclZkRmZZVkdWUkZYU0xacFg3MkIzQ1JPVGsvMEdENlFmeVUzU0liS3NibVhVdnlEM215cnV6d2hiUVZqZ2FYV1dhZThlNnMvTnRSckhXazhySWVnRmhkK3dXVE8zeE1hSW0xL3A3SjFsMVJiYkp6bFFOSmRCZUgyUThPNVVvY1AzZ3U4bWNlUkJ2T2d2M2hKWW8xZDRVOGVMcnlTV3ZxdEtZSUlqU1hWY0pidy9VM2p6STdiSk13dXBBbGl0aWllQWpsL0FVOXd6WXNudnYzMjcvdGRtR25WenJVUFJLdGhBMzV4aXJnVnIxNVJtZ3JBVmhBV2VTbWVKZDlPT25FcHIyL3VESm1xRmRFeXA3WVphVTdXU1A2bkFWdVhOOWFwb0xuZlJYRzVhSnJMV2ZZUzNSZ2ovbnN5cVhlMlhDaDFYQ0Q2L0NKM1hDWjEvWmMxbkRYTlQrMlZDMi9uTWNXOS9JcncyZ0VuSzlnbk1VOWFQcmJyUk42ZnZhWmNHOGxEeDVjQUFhbXZEZDhGV0VCYjREM0hXMVpzM2pXTS9vYVNKT3J4MHFwMHRRbkUzUE5vYTVXSXVJOU1OSlhIa0hXWWZqVmdwRDJTVkw4b2ZlYVBuN0lBQXlRRkJFa2tacS8wWEtiNFRWVlV1RFJSdDFVU2wrSGZQSGtuSnlSYkpXQTBBWVlHbkdENTI0V0ZlM3VTbFN5aTk0a1BBcXkrTFI0UmQzRDdCRlpTZnBBZDRCRHN0cVhMQllQa2ZXUTNMSUpCL3U0ei85TXJOR3hhSDJkMEF3Z0pQczdOS1NyaTJ0c2JGdnRVdGxPOXBhQmRxUFJXTmdpeXk3VXNCL3MwRC9PZit2Sm9QeThETUd3Z0wvS2RoRzNKNStmcjFmdE9tTkZMS1h3blNVdWYzZUhwc1JaSjFOK2hlVVBqSmh3N1pmVFNGcTZvWWFTQ0VCZjZ6MDBNTEcxbHFlcTlYejRZS0dSZUJxNnNxMk9BWmJHaWlWcmdKUWJOWHJjekt6VVhSQ3NJQ2Y2NzA4RlptNXVTbFMwZ0JqVlZ5TnZEU0piVkZuaUpidmFoUk4xVXIrMHlaZk9Mc1dla3BBQWdML0ZsQ0xSNmVuRGgzZHVqTUdTMENBeHFyRkh5Z2dJY0wxTFk4ckZFVnFhcUpTcUViUGNxMGI2L2ROd2NRRnZoelZiVnNjY3FoMUpORHZwcmVTaGZVU0NubkkrTWZQVEtyamtJcXNhenVydGRSQXRqTVg2VWZNM3A3ZkZ4cGNSMkJGWUN3RUdyWjZ0YkgwOU1uZkx1b1RZOXVwQzBLYlhqQTVTbU9JYWdIVC9FYmx5MjBHbDVaRy9EbDFKaURCL2lLZzdZN0JnQkFXS0Jjbm5YanpwMlYyN1lheDQ1cEpRU1JPOGhjRk85UWdzYUY0bEdyWXhUNHg5Sno4bFFqcGV5bEFIL1owTUZocTM4NmRlR0NMUXdzd3JvTEFNSUNGVWRiMWtDR1RIRXMvY3lDdFd1RVQwYVRXU2ptYXF5U045ZHErUHdZc2d4UEc1bkNxbEh6OGhBUDR4VjA5cnRpdnZseVlFQVR0WktjK0VxUVZqNTA4T1R2bHNZZlB2d3dQMStxS3Z5akFBZ0xWSVZkVUVPaDErbUxGOWZ1MmpWeWJwaDg2QkF5VkZQUk1vMVZDZ3ErU0RvVWlObVdUQ2hWa3JYWjV0TzQ2WFZrSlFxZ21xZ1YvSGZwdHpyMDc5dC8ydFR2Tm00NGxKcWFKKzc1eWltU2VCTUFDQXRVTitDeWkzSHlDd3BJWG44a0pDeFl0L2JqT2JQMW40enVPS0RmRzEyN3VBbEJMUUlEMkIwOXRaSmlNZDZhcUZqVnZMbTR2czFyWFl6dCt2WU9HUDd4d09uVFpxNWNzY0ZzVGo1MUtsc2NUbVgzNTNBSEVFQlk0UEhNUlRGWFVaSGptSEtTUzg3RGg1ZHZYRCtXbnA2WWZDUjg5KzR0c1RHL20weS9tU0twYllxTzJwbVlHSGZvMEpGVGFlY3pydDdMeW5LTW0wcjRKOE5UQU1JQ2RaRXRGb3NKWTFGeFVjM214UEI4RTVJQ0VCWjRNZ29UTFZiTUV6b3VvektzVzEzd3crQW5BR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBQUJBV0FBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFDQXNBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBRUJZQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlDd0FBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xBQUFnTEFBQWdMQUFBQkFXQUFCQVdBQUFBR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBQUJBV0FBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFDQXNBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBRUJZQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlDd0FBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xBQUFnTEFBQWdMQUFBQkFXQUFCQVdBQUFBR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBQUJBV0FBRENBZ0FBQ0FzQUFDQXNBQUNFQlFBQUVCWUFBRUJZQUFBSUN3QUFJQ3dBQUlDd0FBQVFGZ0FBUUZnQUFBZ0xBQUFnTEFBQWdMQUFBQkFXQUFCQVdBQUFBR0VCQUNBc0FBQ0FzQUFBQU1JQ0FFQllBQUFBWVFFQUFJUUZBSUN3QUFBQXdnSUFBQWdMQUFCaEFRQUFoQVVBQUJBV0FPQS9oUDhQNmg3S0ZwbEZJaDBBQUFBbGRFVllkR1JoZEdVNlkzSmxZWFJsQURJd01UWXRNRFF0TURkVU1EZzZNRFU2TkRZdE1EUTZNREFla3FkN0FBQUFKWFJGV0hSa1lYUmxPbTF2WkdsbWVRQXlNREUyTFRBMExUQTNWREE0T2pBMU9qUTJMVEEwT2pBd2I4OGZ4d0FBQUJsMFJWaDBVMjltZEhkaGNtVUFRV1J2WW1VZ1NXMWhaMlZTWldGa2VYSEpaVHdBQUFBQVNVVk9SSzVDWUlJPQ=='
```

According to Vision's [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/image-best-practices#image_data), Base64 encoded strings are supported.

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this? I also tried using `vision.detect()` and passing a signed image URL from S3 but got a PEM error `Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` that I can't figure out either. :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the documentation was different back then but... the nodejs client expects a buffer so this should work:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const file = fs.readFileSync('myimage.jpg');
 vision.textDetection({ content: file })
     .then((results) => console.log(results))
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

No need to pass it to base64 format. You only need to do that if are using the REST API.

If you are using s3 the getObject already gives you a buffer

```
var params = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: path
};
s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
 vision.textDetection({ content: s3.body })
     .then((results) => console.log(results))
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

[Cloud vision documentation for nodejs client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/vision/0.12.0/vision)

Comment: This worked for me! If you only have the image in a base64 format, you can convert it back to a buffer by using `let buf = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64');` You can then pass in `buf` to the vision client and it will work!